# Android state based shape overlay (modern approach)

Tags: android, android-layout, mdc-components

I'm looking for a way to customize a specific component android component in a modern Android App.

The behavioral "logic" for the components is pretty much a toggle button ( https://material.io/components/buttons#toggle-button via MaterialButtonToggleGroup) where the user has to select one option out of several in a single row.

However, I can't seem to find a way to customize the shape according to the states or any modern component that allows me the customization option I need. I don't mind using another modern widget.

At the heart of my question is how can I customize the shape ( shapeAppearanceOverlay ) according to the selection state.

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Note: While this might appear as tabs it's not. although I don't mind using a tab strip

Any suggestion for an elegant solution?

Comment: A [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable) may be useful.

Comment: It's not drawbles , Seeting the shape is don't via hapeAppearanceOverlay